# How to edit environment variables without rebuild in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I usually set my API URLs in `environment.ts` file. I have to deploy the same build to multiple clients with different API URLs. Currently I am taking separate builds after changing the environment variables.

Is there any way to edit environment variables after build, so I can give the same build to each client?

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7506 and the issues it links to. There are other ways to achieve runtime configuration, the environment feature is for build time config https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments.

Answer (score 11):

I researched this issue and this is my solution without using `environment.ts`

I defined global settings in json file. Because if we defined in ts file, if build in production mode it is not easy to find constants to change value.

```
export class SettingService  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }



public getJSON(file): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get("./assets/configs/" + file + ".json");
  }
  public getSetting(){
      // use setting here
  }
}
```

In app folder, i add folder configs/setting.json

Content in setting.json

```
{
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:52555"
}
```

In app module add `APP_INITIALIZER`

```
 {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (setting: SettingService) => function() {return setting.getSetting()},
      deps: [SettingService],
      multi: true
    }
```

with this way, I can change `baseUrl` value in json file easier.

Comment: This helped me! The only thing I would add is that in the place that says '// use setting here', you can assign the value of `this.getJson('setting').subscribe(url => this.somevariable = url)`. Then you can use that variable in your components injecting the `SettingService`. I struggled with this thought process, but eventually succeeded with this answer. Thank you.

Comment: This is essentially what we are doing too. I came here looking to see if anyone else had come up with a better solution. We built into our build and deploy pipeline the ability to swap out the config file when deploying to a target as well.

Comment: @Hien Nguyen:sir once above procedure is done....we have upload only config file in the server instead of whole build am i correct?

Comment: @Kapil yes, only setting.json file need