# Modifying environment variable through user input in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently creating an angular application that uses a `REST API` to send and receive calls from an instance at the backend. Currently, this URL is defined as an environment variable as below:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  loggerLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.DEBUG,
  disableConsoleLogging: false,
  lang: 'en',
  api: {
    . //other variables
    .
    .
    host: "http://mycoolurl.com/rest/v11_1/",
    . 
    . //more variables
    .
  }
};
```

Now, there is a similar question that addresses this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626547/how-to-edit-environment-variables-without-rebuild-in-angular-6) but even that uses a specific settings.json file that would be fetched using `APP INITIALIZER`. Another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528824/pass-environment-variables-to-an-angular2-app) also suggested me to use a separate JSON file.

A recent requirement change stated that the user should be able to specify the URL that he wants to send the `REST` calls to, so preferably it would be an input field that he would be entering the URL into and it would update the host in the environment file. How do I achieve this?

Unfortunately, I cannot change the entire implementation and remove the host from the environment, it is being imported and used in so many places throughout the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really change the value of the environment directly in the code because it is bundled with everything else. It is also a really bad approach because you would overwrite the value everytime you update the application. Store it separately server-side!

**Option A:**

Use the APP_INITIALIZER and overwrite the value of the environment there, after loading it:
`environment.api.host = loadedValue`

That will only work properly if you don't use the value before that. It would only be used before that if you use it in module definitions / configuration and classes that you inject into the initializer. So that might work for you.

**Option B**

This is rather ugly but would work fine:

Save the api url in a separate javascript file that looks somewhat like this:

```
window.userEnvironment = { host: "http://custom-host" };
```

Load this javascript in the `<head>` part of the `index.html` with: `<script src="user-env.js"></script>`. That way it is *loaded* before angular is loaded. This is ensured by the browser!

Now inside the `environment.ts` file you can do this:

```
export const environment = {
  ...
};

const userEnv = (window as any).userEnvironment;
if (userEnv) Object.assign(environment, userEnv);
```

This overwrites the environemt value with the values from the `user-env.js` file.

You dont have to do that in the environment. You could also do it somewhere else. You just have to be sure to do it before `environment` is used. Also, if you have multiple environment you would need to it in all environment files.